# UINavigationItem on the UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So I created a UINavigationBar and set it up as an outlet in the .h and .m files. I also connected them in the interface builder. It is working fine.

I need to set a label to the Navigation Bar, and I understand that I need to setup an UINavigationItem for this work. I had setup outlets for the UINavigationItem and connected them via the user interface. It is not appearing when I build and run it.

Am I missing something ? Or do I just need to create an UILabel and place it over the Navigation Bar ?

Comment: Can you share the code you use to create and populate the UINavigationItem? Are you changing the `title` property on the navigation item? Are you pushing the navigation item onto the bar with `pushNavigationItem:animated:`?

Comment: I am not populating the UINavigationItem. I am just setting a Label 'Login' on the UINavigationBar.

Comment: When I go to the interface builder and I doubleclick on the UInavigationBar for labeling it 'Login' and connect it to the outlet of UINavigationItem, it still does not appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the navigation item's title property for this:

```
UINavigationItem *item = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"] autorelease];
[yourNavigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
```